# Samsung SM-V101F 4G port forward

Tags: router, port-forwarding, bittorrent

I bought Samsung SM-V101F 4G hotspot router, and I tried to download torrents using uTorrent, and I was shocked of the slow speed (max 120 Kbps), I think the issue is because of port forwarding which is missing in the samsung mini router.
Is there any solution for this issue?

Please note I was using Hawauei mini-router before using this one, and I was getting perfect speed without port forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

On my Samsung SM-V101F ("Sosh Domino 4G" in France).

I use `http://192.168.1.1/`  ==> user/pass (admin/admin by default) ==> settings.

I don't know if this the same.

Comment: The question is about the speed, not about accessing the admin interface.